# Revealing hidden elements from a dropdown with Alpine.js

Tags: javascript, alpine.js

I'm using Alpine.js on a site and I want to have a dropdown with the options show/hide with alpine, but also when you click on one of the options, it hides/shows blocks of content further down the page.

So far I have this:

```
<div x-data="{ open: false }">
  <button @click="open = !open">Dropdown</button>
  <ul
    x-show="open"
    @click.away="open = false"
  >
    <li><a href="#">One</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Two</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

How would I modify that so that when I click on the dropdown options, it shows the element related to it?

It seems that the `x-data` attribute needs to wrap both the element that is clicked on and the element that will be shown, but I can't nest the additional content I want to show within the dropdown list items.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> It seems that the `x-data` attribute needs to wrap both the element that is clicked on and the element that will be shown, but I can't nest the additional content I want to show within the dropdown list items.

This is one way to do it where you store "selected element" on the same Alpine.js component, obviously you mention that it doesn't suit your purpose.

The alternatives to this are twofold, the first is to use custom events to communicate between Alpine.js components (which is the only Alpine.js native way to do this). The second is to use the [Spruce](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@ryangjchandler/spruce) package to create global stores to share state. I won't be covering the Spruce approach here, it should consist of setting global store state in one component and consuming it from the other component.

To use custom events, in the dropdown, on click of the links (anchor tags), you can use the `$dispatch` magic property (which is just a wrapper around CustomEvent/dispatchEvent) to dispatch a custom event with any data values you wish (they'll be stored under `customEvent.detail`).

In your "receiving" Alpine.js component, you should listen for the "custom event" on the window/document using the `.window` or `.document` modifier respectively. When the listener for the custom event is triggered you can access `$event.details` (note that `$event` is a "magic property") and read whatever data was passed during dispatch of the event.

```html
<div x-data="{ open: false }">
  <button @click="open = !open">Dropdown</button>
  <ul
    x-show="open"
    @click.away="open = false"
  >
    <li><a href="#" @click="$dispatch('dropdown-select', { element: 'one' })">One</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" @click="$dispatch('dropdown-select', { element: 'two' })">Two</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div x-data="{ selected: '' }" @dropdown-select.window="selected = $event.detail.element">
  <div x-show="selected === 'one'">One showing</div>
  <div x-show="selected === 'two'">Two showing</div>
</div>
```

You can see the above example working in the following [CodePen](https://codepen.io/hugodf/pen/abvGegY?editors=1000).